# Flutter post to API from Textfield and DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following form to post data to api. the form has textfields and dropdownbuttons as follows. How can I map to the API and post to api?

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
        child: Form(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Job Title'),
                  controller: titleController,
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Company'),
                  controller: companyController,
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                ),
                DropdownButton(
                  value: currentValue,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  items: <String>[
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                  ].map((String i) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: i,
                      child: Text(i),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: onChangedCallback,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                DropdownSearch<String>(
                  mode: Mode.MENU,
                  showSearchBox: false,
                  showClearButton: true,
                  items: ["Aviation", "Arts", "Business"],
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Category",
                    hintText: "Select Job Category",
                  ),
                  onChanged: print,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Location'),
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 3,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Description'),
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Salary'),
                  onChanged: (val) {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 114, 2)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Add",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I want the textfields to get data and post to api while dropdownbuttons have an item and post the item with the corresponding item name on the api? (Like from the following dropdown buttton  `DropdownButton( value: currentValue, icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down), items: <String>[ "1", "2", "3", ].map((String i) { return DropdownMenuItem( value: i, child: Text(i), ); }).toList(), onChanged: onChangedCallback, ),`
if I select 1, it will post 1 to the api and the same for category. How can this be implmented? )

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use an HTTP client package like [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) or [tttp](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Then you will need to make an api call using this package whenever you click the button.

So an example using Dio package would be like that

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
void postHttp() async {
  try {
    var response = await Dio().post('your-api-link',data: {'title': "job title field", 'currentValue': 'current value field'});
    print(response);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

And you will find more info in the package documentation.

Quick hint:

try to test your api using postman first to make sure it works correctly